# Within a SharePoint site, what is are my options to apply a javascript file to every document library that is created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I want to apply a javascript file like:

```
$('#MyDiv a').click(function(fn) {
  window.open(this.href);
  fn.preventDefault   (); 
});
```

to make it so that all links in document libraries take you to a new window instead of opening the document inside that window. I can do this on one specific page, but I'm new to sharepoint's setup. I've seen some people create lists containing JS files and link to them there through CEWP's, but I don't know much about that either.. if that's how I should go about it then please let me know and I will continue my research in that area.

Answer (score 1):

The following three options are commonly used:

- Add the Script reference to the Master Page
- Use a Delegate Control (e.g. the `AdditionalPageHead`)
- `CustomAction` element in a Feature

### Script reference to the Master Page

[ScriptReference Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - registers an ECMAScript (JavaScript) file for use on an ASP.NET Web page (master page).

```
<asp:ScriptReference Path="<%$SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style Library/scripts/navigation.js%>"/>
```

### Delegate Control

On every master page the following DelegateControl is declared:

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" 
          ControlId="AdditionalPageHead" 
          AllowMultipleControls="true"/>
```

The [DelegateControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.delegatecontrol.aspx) provides a plugin framework for SharePoint, telling ASP.NET to find any registered delegate controls, and for each call the LoadControl method to load your control.

For a more details follow article [Adding jQuery to Every Page in SharePoint with Delegate Controls](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/06/adding-jquery-to-every-page-in-sharepoint-with-delegate-controls.aspx)

### `CustomAction` element in a Feature

In addition to referencing JavaScript Files via Master Pages, there is another technique using the `ScriptSrc` attribute of the `CustomAction` element in a Feature:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
      ScriptSrc="ajax/navigation.js"
      Location="ScriptLink"
      Sequence="80" >
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Please refer an article [REFERENCING JAVASCRIPT FILES WITH SHAREPOINT 2010 CUSTOM ACTIONS USING SCIPTSRC](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2010/03/01/scriptsrc-referencing-javascript-files-with-sharepoint-2010-custom-actions.aspx) for a details

Advantages:

- No need to modify(or create) master page

I would prefer the last option in that example

Comment: Would each subsite have it's own master page if I wanted to included a js script across all pages for only a specific subsite? office365, sharepoint online version.

Comment: It only depends what is the scope of feature. For example, if you need to apply only to a specific sub site, create feature with a web scope and activate it on this sub site.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use custom action to add script block to document libraries.
You can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms473643%28v=office.14%29.aspx) how to create and deploy custom action.

Your custom action will look something like this:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
      Location="ScriptLink"
      Sequence="100"
      RegistrationId="101" 
      RegistrationType="List"
      ScriptBlock="$('#MyDiv a').click(function(fn) {window.open(this.href);fn.preventDefault   (); });"
      >
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

EDIT:

Also you do not need to create click event handler in order to make anchor open in new window. Just set "target" attribute of anchor to "_blank".

```
$('#MyDiv a').each(function() {
   $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
});
```